# Java 8 update 60 getData replacing newlines with spaces

Tags: java, xml, java-8, newline, whitespace

In my code I am reading out the data from xml which is having newlines and no spaces. But recently with Java 8 update 60, while reading data using the `org.w3c.dom.CharacterData.getData()` all the newlines are replaced with spaces.
Now I have to replace all the spaces back to newlines using `replaceAll(" ", "\n")`.
Is there a better way or API to be used.

Here is where I am reading down the element.

```
Node childNode = searchElement.getFirstChild();
while (childNode != null)
{
    if (childNode.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
    {
       contentValue = ((Text)childNode).getData();
       break;
    }
    childNode = childNode.getNextSibling();
}
```

where `Node` is `org.w3c.dom.Node` and `searchElement` is the element I'm looking for which is a resultant of an XPATH query.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your relevant source code.

Comment: Are you trying to write your own XML parser?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem.  Please verify that you are not passing `true` to [DocumentBuilderFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace-boolean-).

Comment: I tried down the setting the property for parser using same. But this didn't helped out